# C# Check array for string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, contains

I'm Year 1 student so I don't know much about c# yet....
Is there any way to check if user inputed array contains a certain string?
 If so I need to add a value to another array.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>           
{
    ["H1"] = "100",
    ["O1"] = "56",
    ["H2"] = "88",
    ["O2"] = "46",
    ["H3"] = "77",
    ["O3"] = "37",
    ["H4"] = "66",
    ["O4"] = "28",
    ["H5"] = "56",
    ["O5"] = "20",
    ["H6"] = "46",
    ["O6"] = "12",
    ["H7"] = "37",
    ["O7"] = "0",
    ["H8"] = "0",
    ["O8"] = "0",
};     

//input grades/subject
int s;
int g;
int p;

string[] grades = new string[6];
string[] subjects = new string[6];
string[] points = new string[6];

// Accepting value from user 
for (s = 0, g = 0,p=0; s <= 5; s++, g++,p++)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter your subject:\t");
    subjects[s] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    subjects[s] = subjects[s].ToUpperInvariant();


    Console.Write("\nEnter your grade:\t");
    grades[g] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    grades[g] = grades[g].ToUpperInvariant();
    if (!lookup.TryGetValue(grades[g], out points[p]))
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong Grade Format!");

}

Console.Clear();
for (s = 0, g = 0,p=0; s <= 5; s++, g++,p++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,15}:{1}:{2}", subjects[s], grades[g],points[p]);//output
}
```

I need to check array that is created by user and if there is Math then +25points has to be added

Comment: It is possible.  Can you show what you've done to try to resolve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried regEx?

Comment: Why do you have three variables (`s`, `p` and `g`) which will always be the same? Have you considered creating a `Student` class with properties for `Grades`, `Subjects` and `Points`? (Generally having "parallel collections" like this is a bad idea.)

Comment: Sry I'm 1st year student ,therefore I did it as I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to check if [..] array contains certain string

Yes there is. The method is called even exactly like this. 
First make sure that you are using the necessary namespace:

```
using System.Linq;


if (subjects.Contains("MATH"))
{
    // do what ever is needed
}
```

ps. Consider following the advise by Jon Skeet

**EDIT:**

as you actually can follow the value entering process of the user step by step you could also check immediately whether the input matches your criterion:

```
// Accepting value from user 
for (s = 0, g = 0,p=0; s <= 5; s++, g++,p++)
{
    Console.Write("\nEnter your subject:\t");
    string input = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    if (input.ToUpperInvariant() == "MATH")
    { /* do what ever is needed */}
    subjects[s] = input.ToUpperInvariant();
```

**EDIT 2:**

Since you increment all 3 variables in your for-loop exactly the same way, you can use only 1 variable and index every array with the same one:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
    subjects[i]...
    grades[i]...
    points[i]...
}
```

Comment: I don't have a chance to test it now but I think I was trying this and Contains would not color in

Comment: @EduardsRatniks would not color in? what do you mean?

Comment: @EduardsRatniks you can also catch the user input and check whether it matches right away. See my edit

Comment: can you add second condition?

Comment: @EduardsRatniks You can add as many conditions as you want. What kind of condition do you have in mind?

Comment: if Subject is Math and grade is higher than H6

Comment: @EduardsRatniks this depends strongly on how you would compare the grades. Since `grades` is an array of type `string` you need to know how to process it to make it comparable. What decides whether a grade is higher? the number behind the `H`? if you want to have two conditions checked you can combine them with `&&` (speaking: AND) like this: `if(input == "MATH" && grade > ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I redesigned your code implementing some custom classes so you can get some ideas:

```
class Student
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public List<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
    public Student(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Grades = new List<Grade>();
    }    
}
class Grade
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> lookup = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["H1"] = "100", ["O1"] = "56", ["H2"] = "88", ["O2"] = "46", ["H3"] = "77",
        ["O3"] = "37", ["H4"] = "66", ["O4"] = "28", ["H5"] = "56", ["O5"] = "20",
        ["H6"] = "46", ["O6"] = "12", ["H7"] = "37", ["O7"] = "0", ["H8"] = "0", ["O8"] = "0",
    };
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Student s = new Student("new student");

        // Accepting value from user 
        while (s.Grades.Count < 6) //amount of grades you want to input
        {
            Grade g = new Grade();
            string points = string.Empty;

            Console.Write("\nEnter your subject:\t");
            //There's no need to convert consoleReadLine to string
            g.Subject = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant();

            //keep asking while the user doesn't insert a valid grade lookup code
            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(points))
            {
                Console.Write("\nEnter your grade:\t");
                g.Code = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant();

                if (!lookup.TryGetValue(g.Code, out points))
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Grade Format!");
                else
                    g.Points = int.Parse(points);
            }
            //points modification condition
            if (g.Subject.Equals("Math", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                g.Points += 25;

            //add the grade data to the student's grades
            s.Grades.Add(g);
        }
        Console.Clear();
        //output using a Linq query
        s.Grades.ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("{0,15}:{1}:{2}", g.Subject, g.Code, g.Points)); 
    }
```